# Listening on multiple TCP ports

Tags: c#, tcp

I am trying to do the following:

```
// Create IPv4 TCP/IP sockets. 
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 11000);
TcpListener listener2 = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 12000);

// Listen for incoming connections.
listener.Start();
listener2.Start();
```

The second call to TCPListener.Start() throws a socketexception saying that "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted".

Since I am using a different port, I thought a server app can listen on multiple ports?

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Is `12000` port free when you start your application?

Comment: are you sure there is no other program listening port 12000 in your computer? try to run netstat -a command to find all listening ports before application runs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is ok and works on my box. The firewall pop up appeared only after both listeners started succesfully.
As everybody is pointing out, you have an application open at port 12000.

Execute `netstat -a -b` and look up which application is using it.

Example:

```
  TCP    [::]:12000             [::]:0                 LISTENING
 [services.exe]
```

Answer (score 2):

An app can set up a tcp listener on any number of ports.

As the error indicates, there is something else listening on that particular port.

My guess is that your app is running twice OR you haven't properly cleaned up after it.  Note that you have to explicitly close each accepted connection individually.  Stop doesn't do this for you.

Reference on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx).